# Relative Bertini theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, flatness, projective-schemes

**Setup of the problem :** Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a flat(smooth) projective morphism with relative dimension $d \geq 1$ and relative very ample sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

**Q :** Is it possible to find a section of $\mathcal{O}(n) \otimes f^*\mathcal{L}$ for all $n >> 0$ and some  (Can we write ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $Y$?) line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $Y$, such that $Z(s)$, the zero set of $s$, is flat(smooth) over $Y$?

If $Y = k$, and we replace flatness by smooth, we get the standard Bertini theorem. I presume that this is a weaker condition and perhaps it admits some generalization in this form.

**My thoughts so far :** Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a smooth projective scheme $Y$ over $k(= \overline{k})$, and let $X = \mathbb{P}(E) \xrightarrow{\pi} Y $, the projective bundle associated to $E$. For any $n$ large enough, I can find $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{L})$ for an ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $Y$. This can be done as follows : We know that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{L}) = \Gamma(Y, Sym^n E \otimes \mathcal{L})$. For $n$ large enough the rank of $Sym^nE$ is greater than $dim(Y)$ and thus can find a everywhere non-vanishing section of $Sym^n E \otimes \mathcal{L}$ for some ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$. This section gives us a section of $\mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{L}$ such that $dim(Z(s)) < dim(X)$ and $Z(s) \rightarrow Y$ is flat. The issue is we cannot repeat this argument again with $X = Z(s)$, since $X$ maynot be projective bundle of a vector bundle.

Hence the reformulation of the above problem in a more general setup. I am in fact only interested in the case of $Y$ and as a consequence $X$ being projective varieties.

Thanks.

Added on August 16, 2021 : I have been unable to find such a theorem in the literature but I am far from an expert. I would appreciate a proof and if not perhaps an outline or a counterexample in case the desired statement is false for both the smooth and flat scenario.

Comment: Even in the usual Bertini, you can not do this with ample line bundles, you need sufficiently ample (for example all large powers) to achieve it.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You should allow twisting your line bundle by pull back of line bundles from $Y$ and then it can be done. Otherwise, easy to construct examples where $\mathcal{O}(n)$ has no sections for any $n$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the comment. I have revised the question appropriately. May I ask for a reference for the statement in this generality?

Comment: Ok, here is one more comment-after this please tell me what you have tried. If the relative dimension of $f$ is zero, you can not do this, so you must assume that the relative dimension is positive.

Comment: @Mohan Sorry for the long delay. I have added few thoughts on the problem.

Comment: This does not work for smoothness, even for very simple examples. Consider for instance the trivial family $X:=P^1\times P^1\to P^1=:Y$. Any section $s$ of the sheaf you propose would define a curve $C\subset P^1\times P^1$. However the corresponding morphism $C\to P^1$ is typically not smooth; it will be ramified along a divisor.